# Jquery $.ajax not posting a string of data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I am building the json data to post dynamically. so I create it in a for loop and then attempt to use the $.ajax command, but on the server side the model is null. If I hard code the data section as would be normal, it works fine. I tried the same process with a simple model just to check and the same happens.

So this works:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SetupQuestions", "Login")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {SharedSecret: 'Bob'},     
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                $('#divMFAQuestion').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("MFA Challenge Error (b): " +  error);
            }
        });
```

But this doesn't:

```
        var datastring = '{SharedSecret: Bob}';
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SetupQuestions", "Login")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(datastring),                
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                $('#divMFAQuestion').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("MFA Challenge Error (b): " +  error);
            }
        });
```

Nor this:

```
 var datastring = 'SharedSecret: Bob';
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You have quotes around your json in datastring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have quotes around your entire JSON data structure:

```
var datastring = '{SharedSecret: Bob}';
```

`JSON.stringify` expects a JSON structure, so the quotes should only be around the string part for `JSON.stringify` to work:

```
var datastring = {SharedSecret: 'Bob'};
```

However, the reason that your AJAX call is not working is that the `data` parameter accepts a JSON data structure. `JSON.stringify` will serialize it as a string, which `data` does not expect. So you need to just pass the fixed `datastring` without `JSON.stringify`.

```
data: datastring
```

Comment: More correctly, shouldn't it be `{SharedSecret: 'Bob'}`?

Comment: Works after removing the processData = false and JSON.stringify(). ThankS!